# Convert factors into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset with PatientID and their Disease test results and they are as follows :

```
Id  Result
1   Strep A: Positive
2   Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative
3   Rsv: Positive, RsvA: Negative, RsvB: Positive
4   Strep A: Negative
5   Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative
6   Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative
7   Strep A: Positive
```

How can I split the `Result` column as follows :

```
Id  Result_Strep A  Result_Flu A    Result_Flu B    Result_Rsv  Result_RsvA Result_RsvB
1   Positive        NA              NA              NA          NA          NA
2   NA              Negative        Negative        NA          NA          NA
3   NA              NA              NA              Positive    Negative    Positive
4   Negative        NA              NA              NA          NA          NA
5   NA              Negative        Negative        NA          NA          NA
6   NA              Negative        Negative        NA          NA          NA
7   Positive        NA              NA              NA          NA          NA
```

dput of data

```
structure(list(Id = 1:7, Result = c("Strep A: Positive", "Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", 
"Rsv: Positive, RsvA: Negative, RsvB: Positive", "Strep A: Negative", 
"Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", "Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", 
"Strep A: Positive")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` to split at the `,`, then `separate` the column into two, and reshape into 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   separate_rows(Result, sep=", ") %>% 
   separate(Result, into = c("Result1", "Result2"), sep=":\\s*") %>% 
   mutate(Result1 = str_c("Result_", Result1)) %>%
   # in case of duplicate elements uncomment the commented code below
   #group_by(Result1) %>%       
   #mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   #ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Result1, values_from = Result2)# %>%
   #select(-rn)
# A tibble: 7 x 7
#     Id `Result_Strep A` `Result_Flu A` `Result_Flu B` Result_Rsv Result_RsvA Result_RsvB
#  <int> <chr>            <chr>          <chr>          <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      
#1     1 Positive         <NA>           <NA>           <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       
#2     2 <NA>             Negative       Negative       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       
#3     3 <NA>             <NA>           <NA>           Positive   Negative    Positive   
#4     4 Negative         <NA>           <NA>           <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       
#5     5 <NA>             Negative       Negative       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       
#6     6 <NA>             Negative       Negative       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       
#7     7 Positive         <NA>           <NA>           <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:7, Result = c("Strep A: Positive", 
 "Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", 
"Rsv: Positive, RsvA: Negative, RsvB: Positive", "Strep A: Negative", 
"Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", "Flu A: Negative, Flu B: Negative", 
"Strep A: Positive")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Works great !! Can you suggest me some documentation or material to get familiar with the dplyr and other packages you've used @akrun , as this is my first project with R so it is taking me so time to get used to this

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia  You can check the vignettes for tidyverse to get a quick understanding of the various functions and its use and then do some practice on those functions.  Practice makes a huge difference

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun